# How to expand the label text just like facebook?

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

This is how i want to expand my label, when I tap the "see more" button.

Comment: you can do this with increase label hight when button click See More. and you also have increase your view hight . at same time

Comment: I know this but the question is how ?

Comment: Do you need some code ?

Comment: I need solution..

Comment: This question has already been answered many times.  [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel) would do for you.

Comment: Has anyone simple code of TTTAttributedLabel in swift for this situation..?

Comment: without link means without underline..